# How to paste content from system Clipboard to an OLE control inserted by Microsoft RichText Control in powerbuilder 6.5?

Tags: ole, powerbuilder, paste

a powerscript example in PB6.5 :

```
ole=Create OleObject         //create an ole control
ole.ConnectToNewObject("word.application")  //connect the ole to word app
ole.Documents.Open(ls_path)  //open an winword using the path "ls_path"
ole.Selection.WholeStory     //ctrl+A
ole.Selection.copy()         //copy the content to system clipboard
```

And now I want to paste this content to another ole control(such as ole_1) connected with Microsoft RichText Control, but I don't know how to do...

That is to say, I can use mouse or use ctrl+V to paste the content successfully, and i cannot find the specific function to complete the operation.

Or is there any document describing the Microsoft Richtext control(version 5.0 in PB6.5)?
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [Implementing the Microsoft Rich Edit Control](http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/117344), by Bruse Armstrong & Demetrios Tsakiris, PowerBuilder Developer's Journal, August 2005